# How does string truthiness work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, casting

I wanted to look for records where a certain string field was not blank or null, so I simply wrote `SELECT ... FROM myTable WHERE x`, assuming that blank and null strings would evaluate to false, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

The string "02306" is true, whereas "N06097EIP" is somehow false.

What's going on?

**Edit:** I'm aware of the workarounds, I simply want to know how the casting works.

Comment: can you explain yourself better? what have you tried? any exampe?

Comment: why don't you use 'is null'? or something like ifnull(myfield,'')=''

Comment: @jcho360: Huh? I gave two examples. I want to know why the former string is considered true, and the latter string is considered false. This is *not* a problem in my code.

Comment: @heximal: Does `ifnull` check for empty strings as well?

Comment: no, but you may convert null values to empty string with ifnull and then compare it with empty string literal.

Comment: What is `x`'s data type?

Comment: @nos: I wrote a select query, `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myString` and it skipped records that actually had text in that field. I then ran another query, `SELECT myString, NOT(NOT(myString)) FROM myTable` and observed the same behaviour. "02306" came back as "1" and "N06097EIP" came back as 0.

Comment: @njk: Specifically, a `varchar(25)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these expression string are first converted to numbers. "02306" is converted to 2306 which is >0 and therefore considered `true`, while "N06097EIP" (starting with non-digit) is converted to 0, which is evaluated as `false`.

Compare results of:

```
select convert("N06097EIP",signed)
```

and

```
select convert("02306",signed)
```

Comment: Even if the type is `varchar(25)`, it will try casting it to an integer first? I find that a bit bizarre.

Comment: Welcome to MySQL. ;] IMHO it shoudn't even actually allow C-like pseudo boolean expressions like the one you used. :]

Comment: @Mark: doesn't matter what the type of the expression `x` is... what matters is that MySQL interprets it in a boolean context, which means that whatever type `x` is, it will be converted to an integer value and evaluated... it will either be NULL, 0 or not-zero, which are equivalent to the boolean "truthiness" values of `NULL`, `FALSE` and `TRUE` (respectively)

Answer (score 3):

In a boolean context, such as

```
WHERE x
```

the expression `x` will be evaluated as an integer value. Note that MySQL considers a BOOLEAN as a numeric type.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html

It doesn't matter what type the expression `x` is; it's either an INTEGER type, or it will be converted to an INTEGER type, according to the documented conversion rules.

The end result is that the expression `x` will be evaluated to be either NULL, integer zero, or integer non-zero.

And those correspond to the boolean "truthiness" values of NULL, FALSE and TRUE.

The reason `'02306'` is considered TRUE is because this string converts to integer value 2306, which is non-zero.

The reason `'N06097EIP'` is considered FALSE is because this string converts to integer value 0.

To can run a simple test case to verify:

```
SELECT IF( 0 = 'N06097EIP', 'is zero', 'is not zero')
SELECT 0 = 'N06097EIP'
```

The behavior you observe is entirely expected. It's all pretty straightforward. You may have been caught unawares, because the normative pattern is for us to avoid this type of evaluation and to instead use "workarounds" (as you put it) to return a boolean.

Comment: Well, I've been coding in PHP a lot lately, and PHP's truth-table is a bit different, so.. I guess I just expected it to work the same way. Once you know MySQL tries to cast everything to an integer though, this behaivour makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to be too cute about this with syntactic shortcuts. If nothing else, it's always harder on the next developer who has to figure out what you were doing.

Just spell out what you want.

```
SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE x IS NOT NULL AND x <> '';
```

or, if you'd prefer:

```
SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE COALESCE(x, '') <> '';
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, but I'd still like an explanation.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Comment: 'Tis not I. Your answer wasn't what I was looking for, but I +1'd you for infos.